# How to create a method for JOption Pane in java?

Tags: java, swing, integer, joptionpane

how can I make a method for JOptionPane in java, thats gets and stores the value given by the user in a given variable and converts it into double / int, the variable which I want to store the value in is outside the method and in main class

e.g.

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
    double num1
    int num2

    // calling the method
    method(pane, num1);
    }

    public void method(String pane, double number){
    String pane = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("choose a number");
    number = Double.parseDouble(pane);
    }
}
```

which then can be printed like so

```
system.out.println(num1);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCTRE).

Comment: `method` needs to be `static` or you won't be able to call it from the `main`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the method return `double`. And make `num1 = method()`

Answer (score 2):

`number` will be destroyed when you exit the method as it's *local* to the method. So `num1` will be 0, as it's the default value for `double` and it won't be affected.

You should do something like that:

```
double res; //a class member
..
..
String pane = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("choose a number");
res         = Double.parseDouble(pane);
```

Comment: How does this work, the optionpane is not in a method.

Comment: What does this have to do with the fact that `JOptionPane` is not a method?